# WPF: CroppedBitmap as Source in XAML displays nothing

Tags: wpf, xaml, bitmap

Not sure what the issue is here. If I do the following:

```
<Image Width="90" Height="97" Source="<some path>" />
```

My image shows up as expected. But I want to crop it so I use the following code with the exact same path.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <CroppedBitmap Source="<same path>">
            <CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                <Int32Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="100" Height="100" />
            </CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
        </CroppedBitmap>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And nothing shows up. Can anyone tell me why it's not working? I'm using a PNG if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with a gif. In Visual Studio 2012, the image does not show up in the design view, but when I actually run the application, the cropped image shows up just fine.